# Orchard Core "umlaut" (German Character) Problem

Tags: character-encoding, special-characters, orchardcms, orchard-modules

I have a Setup.recipe.json file in which there exists a content item with a html string containing German "umlaut" characters such as "ö" , "ü" etc.  I tried adding several settings to the recipe file and i also enabled all "Internationalization" modules and i also added this code piece to my Startup.cs file:

```
services.Configure<WebEncoderOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.TextEncoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings(UnicodeRanges.All);
            });
```

Despite all these i can not display these characters within the content after saving and publishing it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to ask this kind of question on the https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore repository in the issues or in a discussion.